# Line equation in Python Prophet

Tags: python, facebook-prophet

Please, help: Is there a way to get the chart (line) equation and the R-squared value using Facebook Prophet in Python?

I know Prophet includes a package named "utilities", however I don't know how to get my model's equation for slope, intercept and R-squared value

Thanks!.

Comment: Does [this github issue](https://github.com/facebook/prophet/issues/1784) help?

Comment: Hi @dash thanks for answering. I don't seem to be able to get the params library. Do you have some documentation?